# c# exclude regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I am parsing several text files looking for date fields.  I want to find this pattern - Date: mm/dd/yyyy but want to exlude this pattern - Cheque Date: mm/dd/yyyy.  I have this working for finding the first pattern but it also finds the second pattern as well -

```
string pattern = @"Date:\s*(.+?)\r";
```

Using this pattern I can find all combination of dates and not just mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Use an anchor: `@"^Date:\s*(.+?)\r";` binds it to the beginning of the string.

Comment: try a negative look behind.

Comment: Is the *entire line* "Date: mm/dd/yyyy" or "Cheque Date: mm/dd/yyyy", or could there be other characters before those patterns?

Comment: Try this: https://regex101.com/r/mA5rE4/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment, you may want to use an anchor:

```
string pattern = @"^Date:\s*(.+?)\r";
```